# Winrm and SOAP service using Javascript

Tags: javascript, soap, winrm

Please can anyone help me with sample codes that can utilize the WinRM protocol to get host information of a remote PC from a local PC using javascript and SOAP services?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/winrmjs

It's a Npm package. Not sure how much it is stable and/or production ready, though.